# Set background in linear layout from Bitmap from file

Tags: java, android

I would like to set background in `LinearLayout` from file, path is correct, but not works

```
Bitmap bitmap5 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData().getPath());
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap5);
mDrawingPad.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: `path is correct,` Well show your path. What is the value? `data.getData().getPath()` . We know its not correct ;-)

Comment: After you told that also tell the value of `data.getData().toString()`.

Comment: System.out.println("###"+data.getData().getPath()); - I/System.out: ###/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/kitobidarsi/drawing_11.png

Comment: After you told that also tell the value of `data.getData().toString()`.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons the path will not work, maybe you didn't grant the storage permission or the file path is null or empty, or invalid..., check your logcat

Comment: Permission is ok, because was saved a lot files by my app, it is not null : Logcat: I/System.out: ###/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/kitobidarsi/drawing_11.png
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/kitobidarsi/drawing_11.png (No such file or directory),   but realy I see this file in my mobile

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/kitobidarsi/drawing_11.png");  this works

Comment: You still did not tell the value of `data.getData().toString()` Instead you messed aroud quite a bit obtaining that path..

Comment: Solved but bad solution :  String ddd = data.getData().getPath();
            ddd =ddd.substring(ddd.indexOf(":")+1 ); , What do you think , in different mobiles could be makes errors ?